# What is the difference between outputs in a method with argument and no argument?

Tags: arguments, scheme, racket

What causes the output difference below?

```
 (define my-method (lambda () '(1 2)))

    (define my-method (lambda (x) '(1 2)))
```

First one returns : procedure:my-method

Second one:(1 2)

Comment: No difference. You must have typed something different in the first case other than the argument list.

Comment: There should be no difference, but in Racket neither definition should produce any output at all. Where exactly are you entering these? (And are these *exactly* what you entered? Remember that a pair of parentheses makes a lot of difference in Scheme and Racket.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference:

```
(define my-method1 (lambda () '(1 2)))
(define my-method2 (lambda (x) '(1 2)))

(my-method1)
(my-method2 1)
my-method1
my-method2
```

Outputs:

```
'(1 2)
'(1 2)
#<procedure:my-method1>
#<procedure:my-method2>
```